# jQuery post redirect browser to a different URL

Tags: asp.net, jquery-post

I have a jQuery post to a method in '.asmx' file. It was working well in Firefox 3.5 but not in 4.0. When post happens it redirect to a URL something like 'www.5_124.com'. Don't know what's happening . 
And this is happening for only one method in the 'asmx' file. Others are working correct.

In firebug it says the POST is aborted.

Comment: what exactly firebug log says? Does FF issue a POST request to incorrect URI or FF issues POST request to asmx and then server responds with redirect?

Comment: FF issue POST to correct URL.(asmx function is working fine. I have tested it ).

Comment: if FF issues POST to correct URL, what is the server response? Does redirect get issued by server response?

Comment: FF issues correct post to correct URL and he data in post is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Need to have return false at the end of the drag and drop event. If not it the event will propagate to the browser. Don't know why ff 3.5 having no issue with it :).

```
   function dragDrop(ev) {
    //....
    return false;

    }
```